# NodeJS/PostgreSQL. I can authenticate using arbitrary/any password

Tags: node.js, postgresql

I have the following problem. I created a PostgreSQL user `app` with this statement:

```
CREATE USER app WITH ENCRYPTED PASSWORD 'qwerty';
```

Then I gave it some privileges in my database `bazy`.

Then I access a database by authenticating as this user and using `pg` module like this:

```
const { Pool } = require('pg');

(async function() {
    let pool = new Pool({
        user: "app",
        host: 'localhost',
        database: "bazy",
        password: "BS",
        port: 5432
    });
    let client = await pool.connect();
    let { rows } = await client.query("SELECT 'I love you';");
    console.log(rows);
})();
```

The problem is that this works and gives this output:

```
[ { '?column?': 'I love you' } ]
```

But this should not work, for the password of the user is `qwerty`, not `BS`. And the thing is that any password works here.

What have I done wrong?

**[EDIT]**

The answer of @mike.k is 100% helpful.

The not commented (almost) part of [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file, which we can find following [these instructions](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256534/how-do-i-find-the-path-to-pg-hba-conf-from-the-shell), looks like this:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE        USER            ADDRESS                 METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all             all                                     trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
# Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
# replication privilege.
local   replication     all                                     trust
host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

We can see here that we do not require password in any type of connections listed here, for method `trust` means that in order to connect to those users we are not required any password (it is ignored obviously), in order to change that we can use method `password` or `md5` or `scram-sha-256` instead, as is said in [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) file:

```
# Note that "password" sends passwords in clear text; "md5" or
# "scram-sha-256" are preferred since they send encrypted passwords.
```

To be honest, I don't know where exactly I should change it, though. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯. So I changed all of them (of the `methods` to `password`) and it worked :) It requires passwords now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check your [`pg_hba.conf`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/auth-pg-hba-conf.html) content, it might be configured to not require a password for localhost connections.

Try using the local IP address and you might see that it behaves differently. Or try connecting from another system on the same network.